# swiper.... how to block only first slide swipe to left?

Tags: swiper.js

I created 4 slides by swiper js.

but I need to block only first slide swipe to left. like allowSlidePrev:false...

is there any way to block only first slide to swipe left?

Comment: Could you add the code you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I add the option resistanceRatio: 0

```
          <Swiper
            pagination={{ clickable: true }}
            autoHeight={false}
            effect={"fade"}
            spaceBetween={0}
            modules={[EffectFade, Pagination]}
            breakpoints={{
              320: {
                slidesPerGroup: 1,
                slidesPerView: 1,
                allowTouchMove: true,
                resistanceRatio: 0, <-- here
              },
            }}
          >
            <SwiperSlide>slide 1</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>slide 2</SwiperSlide>
          </Swiper>
```